# COBOL copybook blank fields

Tags: cobol, mainframe, copybook

Simple question that I cannot find an answer to through web-searching.

Is it valid to have a field in a COBOL copybook without a name? i.e. is the following valid?

```
05  SUMMARY.
    07  DETAILS OCCURS 3 TIMES
                            PIC X(10).
    07                      PIC X(100).
```

Is this the same as say using FILLER instead of the name? If not, what is the difference between a blank name and using FILLER?

Comment: Yes, your code is valid COBOL.  FILLER and no name are the same.  I'm used to writing and seeing FILLER because I'm an old-school COBOL developer.

Comment: The usage `no name` instead of `FILLER` was an addition to the Cobol Standard, not sure which version. I prefer it, other don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the same as say using FILLER instead of the name?

Yes it is. The requirement to use `FILLER` for an unreferenced data item was removed in COBOL85.

Using one or the other is mostly a "style" issue, commonly there will be a "shop/team rule" about what to use.

Note: this is not strictly related to a copybook, it is the same when used in any data description entry in the program's source.
For documentation (I assume you meant an IBM mainframe here) see [the appropriate entry in the IBM COBOL Language Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlddefm1.htm).